# Double spacing of output from SubInACL called from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using a PowerShell script to delete data.
Where I do not have access I am using SubInACL.exe to take\set ownership
Note: I then call it again to grant access
Note II: I am aware of TakeOwn.exe and use it elsewhere in the script

I build the command using a here-string:
`[string]$SubInACLCommand = @"`
`subinacl.exe /file "$func_filePath" /setowner="Hostname\Administrators"`
`"@`

Then call it using Invoke-Expression:
`Invoke-Expression $SubInACLCommand`

The output is returned double-spaced:
`\ \ H o s t n a m e \ S h a r e n a m e \ F o l d e r n a m e   :   H o s t n a m e \ A d m i n i s t r a t o r s   i s   t h e   n e w   o w n e r`...

I have not seen this before.  It is as if the output is in some 16-bit character set, where PowerShell ISE is expecting\interpreting it as 8-bit. 
This is not causing me a problem as such.  However any insight would be appreciated as it would be nice to understand and even better to correct.

Comment: `[Console]::OutputEncoding=[Text.Encoding]::Unicode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to find some information to explain but could not, so far.

As advised by @PetSerAl you can change the output encoding to Unicode with `[Console]::OutputEncoding=[Text.Encoding]::Unicode`

```
#set output encoding to unicode
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode

$func_filePath = "G:\test\func.txt"

#use subinacl
[string]$SubInACLCommand = @"
subinacl.exe /file "$func_filePath" /setowner="hostname\Administrators"
"@

Invoke-Expression $SubInACLCommand

#revert output encoding back to default
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Encoding]::Default
```

PS : I know OP has deleted his account ...

Comment: [Sorry for slow reply, it took me a while to understand that this instance of my question is on a different site to where I posted it, giving me problems responding] <br />PetSerAl's comment was enough for me to fix my script, however I can't mark it as an answer.  I have therefore marked sodawillow's as the answer, which is probably more fitting as it shows where to make the initial change (which is earlier than I thought, i.e. it needs to be before the command is issued with Invoke-Expression) and how to set it back (which I had worked out, but is worth making clear).<br />Thank you both.